# Create an reactive auxiliary class in the LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, class

I've tried to create auxiliary classes in the component folder to divide logic into smaller parts, but I can't make the data on the page refresh.

for example:

Example file structure:

```
component/
|-component.html
|-component.js
|-component.css
|-component.js-meta.xml
|-userData.js
```

I've created file `userData.js` that will contains information about user:

**helper class:**

```js
export default class UserData{
  #firstName;
  #lastName;

  constructor(firstName, lastName){
    this.#firstName = firstName;
    this.#lastName = lastName;
  }

  get lastName(){
    return this.#lastName
  }
  set lastName(value){
    if(value.length > 0){
      this.#lastName = value
    }
  }

  // rest of the code
}
```

In the `component.js`, I've imported this class and created an object:

**Main JavaScript:**

```js
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import UserData from './userData';

export default class Component extends LightningElement {
  userData = new UserData('firstName', 'lastName');

  handleOnChange(){
    userData.lastName = 'newLastName';
  }
}
```

And in the `component.html` the data was bound:

**HTML:**

```html
<template>
  <p>{userData.firstName} {userData.lastName}</p>
  <button onclick={handleOnChange}>Click</button>
</template>
```

In this situation, after modifying the data in the object, HTML did not refresh the values.

Is there any way to create an auxiliary class that is reactive?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, an internal state mutation will not be observed by the LWC engine, even though the code uses `@track` decorator on a complex object (e.g. an instance of the custom `UserData` class). But you can try to reassign the `userData` reactive property with a new `UserData` instance:

```js
export default class Component extends LightningElement {
  @track
  userData = new UserData('firstName', 'lastName');

  handleOnChange() {
    this.userData = new UserData('newFirstName', 'newLastName');
  }
}
```

Also if you want to keep the rest of the state of the current `userData` reactive property, you can clone it first, mutate its non-reactive property, and finally reassign the `userData` reactive property.

[Docs: Reactivity for Fields, Objects, and Arrays](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields)

Comment: That's not quite accurate. If the property is not a getter/setter, it will be tracked just fine via track.

Comment: As far as I know and docs say that an internal state mutation of custom classes cannot be observed, it will be really great if you share some working examples))

Comment: No wonder I missed it. The docs mention this all in one short little sentence, easy to miss. I've always just presumed they were handling class instances and objects as the same thing. So, I learned a few new things today. 

Comment: Thanks, I have learned something new today as well. Btw I have found this issue from 2 years ago: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/1655

Answer (score 0):

If fields are changing you should apply `@track` to the property, e.g.

```
@track
userData = new UserData('firstName', 'lastName');
```

See more info on [Decorators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `@track` is not working with the class instance